# Non-Numerical String-based Factor Analysis in R?

Tags: r

I've recently been using a package called GrpString in R.

It allows string-based clustering, where clusters are plotted with the first + second components as axes.

However, I've struggled to find a routine in R which allows for tabulation of factor-based output (equivalent to seeing first and second principal components).

I wondered if anyone was familiar with how to conduct factor-based analysis for strings in R and if they could provide some code?

Would be appreciated.

```
############################
#EXAMPLE OF GRP STRING IN R
#############################

#PACKAGE

devtools::install_github("dstgithub/GrpString")
library(GrpString)

#DATA

strs3.vec <- c("ABCDdefABCDa", "AC3aABCD", "ACD1AB3", "xYZfgAxZY", "gf56xZYx",
"AkfxzYZg")

#K-MEANS CLUSTER OUTPUT WITH COMPONENTS ON EACH AXIS

StrKclust(strs3.vec)
```

Comment: Would you explain what is "factor-based analysis for strings", or provide some examples?

Comment: Hi @ bdedu: 'equivalent to obtaining first + second principal components [in continuous analysis or MCA with categories]' is what i mean.

Comment: There are some discussions, e.g., [PCA  applied to categorical variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont). But applying PCA to categorical data is not encouraged by some people. [if variables don’t belong on a coordinate plane, do not apply PCA](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-is-not-feature-selection-3344fb764ae6).   The functions in package GrpString cluster strings based on  distances, which are numerical. It may be easier if you consider first converting strings to continuous variables.